# senting email with nodemailer and firebase functions with custom email not gmail

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, nodemailer, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to send a simple email with nodemailer and Cloud functions for Firebase, not GMAIL I use my GoDaddy email server, but I have this error on Cloud Functions for Firebase console:

```
{ Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mail.square-boat.gr mail.square-boat.gr:587
        at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
        at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)
      code: 'ECONNECTION',
      errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
      syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
      hostname: 'mail.square-boat.gr',
      host: 'mail.square-boat.gr',
      port: '587',
      command: 'CONN' }
```

This is the function's code on index.js:

```
const mailTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({

  host: 'mail.square-boat.gr',
  auth: {
    user: 'info@square-boat.gr',
    pass: 'xxxxx!'
  },
  secure: false, // use TLS
  port : '587'

});


exports.sendContactMessage = functions.database.ref('/emails/{pushKey}').onWrite(event => {

  const snapshot = event.data;

  // Only send email for new messages.
  if (snapshot.previous.val() || !snapshot.val().name) {
    return;
  }

  const val = snapshot.val();

  const mailOptions = {
    from: 'test@example.com',
    to: 'test@example.com',
    subject: `Information Request from ${val.name}`,
    html: val.html
  };

  return mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions).then(() => {
    return console.log('Mail sent to: test@example.com')
  }).catch( error => {
    console.log(error);
  });

});
```

Comment: Are you using the free [Firebase Spark](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/) plan? It limits outbound networking requests to Google services only.

Comment: yes i use the spark

Comment: bob that is 100% if i go to next firebase plan is gona work??

Comment: You need to move to a paid plan.  I haven't used an external mail transport and can't say of your code is correct or not.  It may need some changes, but you should be able to make it work.